# GTA V requires internet to save progress

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I usually play GTA V at home with my Ethernet cable connected and my 16 GB USB stick to save progress. So far, I've gained 20% completion.

But I'm at a friends house with the same Xbox, and we can't connect it to internet. When we tried to play, we had to start the game over with Mission 1 "Prologue" and for some reason we cant save progress on the USB stick. I think this is because the game requires internet in order to save.

Unfortunately this means each time we start up the Xbox we have to start over.

Is there any workaround or solution to this?

Comment: Does your console have cloud saving enabled? If so, disable it.

Comment: same issue it want me to connect to xbox live to save progress, even though I have my usb plugged in with my progress...

Comment: I have no problem saving my game content without being signed into xbox live.

Comment: I have a 16gb flash drive too, and the same thing happens to me. The only thing I can recommend is to get a hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be because the saved game is strictly for your profile (your gamertag), you won't need the internet to save, but you first need to download your profile to continue the saved game.

Having your cloud enabled can also cause this problem - try disabling it in Storage settings.

Comment: And your gamertag can be downloaded to the same USB stick so that the xbox doesn't have to be connected to the Internet to download it.